TYPO3 - typoscript - special = directory if more then one
i search for a solution, how can i switch the special = directory to special = list if i have more then 1 selected page (in the field = overviewnavigation_pages).
here my normal typoscript MenuProcessor:
dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
            special = directory
            special.value.field = overviewnavigation_pages
            includeSpacer = 0
            as = overviewnavigation
            expandAll = 1
            titleField = nav_title // title

            dataProcessing {
                10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                10 {
                    references.fieldName = teaser_image
                }
            }
        }
    }

thanks for helping

it's probably hard to override the value of special, but you could us conditions to assign a menu depending on the case.
For checking the amount of referenced records I didn't find an existing condition but programming your own condition isn't very difficult.
Before doing that you can search though if a required condition exists provided by an extension. TER: search 'condition'.
And if you've to program an own condition the TYPO3 documentation is helping quite well: Creating custom conditions for TYPO3.
So the concept is about the condition is this with explaining dummy-code:
[COUNT(traverse(page, 'overviewnavigation_pages')) > 1]

... dataProcessing.10.special = list
[else]
... dataProcessing.10.special = directory
[global]

Take into consideration that with 'directory' you get a list of subpages, but the referenced page is missing in the menu (-level).
Having a 'list' shows the entered pages instead and it completely depends on which values are entered which pages are shown.
For both options you can add the configuration "expAll" though, to show also the subpages. In combination with the fluid-template you could filter the referenced pages though to simulate the same behavior like 'directory', just for two or more pages at once.
If you decide to program something, you could use my extension as help, it shows the fundamental file- and class structure you need:
Extension Content Conditions.
